# Convert complex Scala XML with namespaces and properties to Scala objects

Tags: xml, scala, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

It seems really easy to convert normal Scala XML to an object:

`<object><field>1</field></object>` can create something like `Object(1)` using the case class `Object( field: Int )` with Scala's native XML API.

But what if the XML contains namespaces and properties? Such as an ATOM format?

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:activity="http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/" xmlns:service="http://activitystrea.ms/service-provider" xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gnip="http://www.gnip.com/schemas/2010">
<id>456520791711374025_380135597</id>
<published>2013-05-15T18:12:20Z</published>
<source>
<link rel="self" type="application/json" href="https://url.com/v1/tags/taghere/media/recent?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
<updated>2013-05-15T18-12-43Z</updated>
<gnip:rule xmlns:gnip="http://www.gnip.com/schemas/2010">rulehere</gnip:rule>
</source>
<service:provider>
<name>Provider</name>
<uri>www.url.com</uri>
</service:provider>
<activity:verb>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/post</activity:verb>
<activity:object>
<activity:object-type>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/image</activity:object-type>
<gnip:statistics favoriteCount="0"/>
</activity:object>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with more complicated XML formats requires advanced annotation of a particular class. Recommended strategy is to use something like [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/) to annotate each field in the class.

Here's some sample code adapted from http://krasserm.blogspot.ca/2012/02/using-jaxb-for-xml-and-json-apis-in.html:

```
import scala.annotation.meta.field 

//Scala 2.9 or lower uses scala.annotation.target.field
 
import javax.xml.bind.annotation._
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters._
 
type xmlElement     = XmlElement @field
type xmlTypeAdapter = XmlJavaTypeAdapter @field
 
class StringOptionAdapter extends OptionAdapter[String](null, "")
class OptionAdapter[A](nones: A*) extends XmlAdapter[A, Option[A]] {
  def marshal(v: Option[A]): A = v.getOrElse(nones(0))
  def unmarshal(v: A) = if (nones contains v) None else Some(v)
}
 
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
case class Person(
    @xmlElement(required=true) fullname: String, 
    @xmlTypeAdapter(classOf[StringOptionAdapter]) username: Option[String], 
    age: Int) {
  // only needed and accessed by JAXB
  private def this() = this("", None, 0)
}
```

Note that case classes require you to target the specific field, hence the import of `annotation.meta.field`.

FYI you can add JAXB as a dependency here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.xml.bind%7Cjaxb-api%7C2.2.9%7Cjar

### Edit

Though I personally wouldn't prefer it, Xml support is also available through [scalaxb](http://scalaxb.org/). It works as a native plugin and wouldn't necessarily act as a typical Maven dependency. It uses advanced features like XML templates.